# How to Restart iDevice From Webpage on button Click

Tags: html, ios, iphone, ipad

I want to know if it's possible to restart or reboot an iPhone or iPad with HTML. I have a webpage built on my local IP address and I can access the webpage from my phone.

Now I just want to know it it's possible to restart/reboot my iOS device with HTML from a button or link. Is it possible? If not then what's the closest alternative?

Comment: Even native apps running on the iOS device can't cause a reboot (at least while using public APIs any way).

Comment: That would be a massive security risk....

Comment: It would be a little ridiculous if this were possible. Maybe on a jailbroken phone, with a certain plugin, or using a certain browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc it's not possible. thats even sounds like a virus software

Comment: I don't really think its possible to run virus software without the iDevice being Jailbroken though.